# Two ways of block for preventing retain-cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, retain-cycle

I usually use block like this if there might be a retain-cycle:

```
- (void)someFunction {
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self setHandler:^{
        [weakSelf doSomething];
    }];
}
```

But recently I saw another way like:

```
- (void)someFunctionWithParam:(id)param {
    __weak __typeof(param) weakParam = param;
    [self setHandler:^{
        __typeof(weakParam) strongParam = weakParam;
        [strongParam doSomething];
    }];
}
```

What's the difference between them?

Edit1: Does it mean the `param` won't be release when `self` running the handler?

Answer (score 4):

In the second example, there is no benefit to creating the `strongSelf` variable in that specific case, but I can show you an example where there is a benefit.

In the first example, the statement `[weakSelf doSomething]` loads the reference in `weakSelf`, retains it, sends the `doSomething` message, and then (after `doSomething` returns) releases the reference. The second example does essentially exactly the same steps “by hand”.

Here's a slightly different example:

```
- (void)someFunction {
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self setHandler:^{
        [weakSelf doSomething];
        [weakSelf doAnotherThing];
    }];
}
```

In my code, suppose there's only one strong reference to the `self` object at the time the block is called. The `[weakSelf doSomething]` statement creates a second, temporary strong reference to it. While `doSomething` is running, another thread releases the other strong reference. When `doSomething` returns, the statement releases its temporary strong reference. Now `self` has no more strong references, so it is deallocated and `weakSelf` is set to nil.

Then the `[weakSelf doAnotherThing]` statement runs. It wants to load and retain the contents of `weakSelf`, but because `weakSelf` is now nil, the statement just uses nil. It sends the `doAnotherThing` message to nil, which is allowed and doesn't crash. It just does nothing. It doesn't call the method.

This might not be behavior you want. Maybe you **always** want `doAnotherThing` to run on `self` if `doSomething` ran. That's when you need the pattern in your second example:

```
- (void)someFunctionWithParam:(id)param {
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self setHandler:^{
        __typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf doSomething];
        [strongSelf doAnotherThing];
    }];
}
```

Here, when the block is called, it immediately stores a strong reference to `self` in `strongSelf` (or it stores nil if `weakSelf` has already been set to nil). The `strongSelf` reference can't be released until after the last use of the `strongSelf` variable, so it's impossible for `self` to be deallocated after `doSomething` but before `doAnotherThing`.

Comment: Good explanation rob

Comment: Why does it take reference two times?

Comment: Each statement that refers to `weakSelf` runs independently, creating and then releasing a strong reference to the object. That's just how it works.

Comment: Same as I thought. But there's no problem for `self` because when running `[self handler]`, `self` won't be `nil`. But it's possibly nil for `param` before `[self handler]`. If there's needed to obtain the `param`, we should use `[param copy]` to obtain a copy of it, right?

Comment: Then why strongself doAnotherthing returns nil?If do something is creating and releasing strong reference,the same thing should be for do another thing.

Comment: @user3182143 good question. I think you are right, doSomthing might be nil too.

Comment: As I explained, it's possible for the object to be deallocated after the call to `doSomething`, before the call to `doAnotherThing`, unless you've created a strong reference to it that lives across both calls.

Comment: @KleinMioke: "But there's no problem for self because when running [self handler], self won't be nil." Not true. `self` can be deallocated in the middle of running some method on it. "If there's needed to obtain the param, we should use [param copy] to obtain a copy of it, right?" No. Getting copies has absolutely nothing to do with memory management. And most objects cannot be copied.

Comment: @newacct In 2nd case, if `self` won't be deallocated, gain a copy when enter a method it will do work. No copy method we can use `__strong __typeof(param) strongParam` and use strongParam in the block, because the block will gain a copy of the strong pointer. About the first case you are right.

Comment: @KleinMioke: That's just capturing a strong reference; it has nothing to do with `-copy`.